# angular2 define methods scope component only

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Angular2,

in angular1 if we don't add any method in $scope it won't be available to the template.

i am looking for similar approach in angular2, is there a to do the same thing in angular2 where if i define method whose scope is limited to component only and not available to template

Answer (score 3):

Angular2 is very different to AngularJS (1), if you define a method in a components ts file it will only be available within that component, if you really want to make sure define your method as private.

```
private someMethod(): void {
    //do stuff
}
```

The only sensible way to define something outside the scope of a component would be to create a service you inject. TypeScipt is very much Object Orientated JavaScript.

Comment: sorry my bad i want to have method in component which is not available to its template.

Comment: @Faisalkhan Defining it as private is the way you would restrict it to just the code behind.

Comment: sorry but practically thats not true, private methods are available to the templates.

Comment: @Faisalkhan I think what you want to achieve is not possible, as the template and component are one in the same. What's the use case for this?

Comment: sure, some methods for processing which don't need to be on template.

Comment: @Faisalkhan for that situation then you would put a method in a service and then inject that method into the components that require it and leave it out of the ones that don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134013/discussion-between-oliver-cooke-and-faisal-khan).

Comment: This is good advice but isn't quite accurate.  Faisal, yes the private method is "accessible" from the template, with JIT compilation only, because in that case the template is talking to the component as a JS module, which of course doesn't actually have a `private` modifier.  With AOT compilation, the template talks to a TS component, which should result in an error when accessing `private` members.